# Diferencia entre return EXIT_FAILURE Y exit(EXIT_FAILURE) en c

Tags: c

tengo una duda. ¿Qué diferencia hay entre return EXIT_FAILURE Y exit(EXIT_FAILURE) ?
¿y cuando usas una u otra? ¿daría igual usar siempre una?

He visto algunos ejercicios sobre sistemas de ficheros en donde los métodos utilizan exit(EXIT_FAILURE) y en el main return EXIT_FAILURE, pero no entiendo muy bien porqué.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si consultamos el [estándar de C](https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359if_/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf) (traducción y resaltado míos):

> #### 5.1.2.2.3 Terminación del programa
>
> Si el valor de retorno de la función `main` es un tipo compatible con `int`, **el retorno de la llamada inicial a la función `main` es equivalente a llamar a la función `exit` con el valor devuelto por la función `main` como argumento**. Alcanzar el `}` que finaliza la función `main` devuelve el valor `0`.

Vemos que las instrucciones `return EXIT_FAILURE;` y `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` desde `main` son equivalentes. La instrucción `return EXIT_FAILURE` en cualquier otra función diferente a `main` no es equivalente a llamar a `exit`.

> ¿Cuándo usas una u otra?

Mi consejo es que uses `exit` siempre que quieras finalizar el programa y no estés en `main`.